# Error en Spyder | No actualiza ni abre

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder, actualizacion

Tras largo tiempo sin usar el programa **(Spyder)** intenté hacerlo. Pero para mi sorpresa, al ejecutarlo comunmente éste simplemente lazaba una ventanilla sugiriendo la actualización a 4.0.1.

Tras actualizarlo por orden dentro de la distribución **Anaconda**, vuelvo a ejecutarlo, encontrándome con la misma ventana anteriormente lanzada.

Ante esto desinstalo **Anaconda Spyder** y **Python** para reinstalarlo. Cuando ejecuto en esta nueva ocasion **Spyder** me encuentro otra vez con la ventanilla de solicitud de actualización a 4.0.1, por lo que recurro a actualizar **Anaconda** exitosamente e intento actualizar **Spyder** a traves del **Símbolo de Sistema** de **Windows**, lo cual me arroja el siguiente error:

```
C:\Users\pc>pip install -U spyder
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/spyder/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/spyder/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/spyder/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/spyder/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/spyder/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/spyder/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/spyder/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: spyder in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (3.3.6)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: qtawesome>=0.5.7 in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spyder) (0.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pycodestyle in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spyder) (2.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pickleshare in c:\users\pc\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from spyder) (0.7.5)
Collecting pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3" (from spyder)
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pyqt5/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pyqt5/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pyqt5/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3" (from spyder) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5<5.13; python_version >= "3" (from spyder)
```

Agradecería su ayuda, de otra forma no veo solución a esto, ya que ni siquiera reinstalando todo ésto se solucionó.

Comment: Prueba usando pip a través de la consola de Anaconda no a través de CMD. Mírate https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/issues/1139, parece ser un problema de Anaconda (por dónde localiza los módulos de la stdlib de Python) y el PATH que impide al intérprete encontrar el módulo ssl necesario al usar PyPI el protocolo https.

Comment: @FJsevilla  acabo de eliminar todos los venv, ordene la actualizacion mediante anaconda prompt y logro actualizarlo, pero aun asi al ejecuytar spyder este ya no muestar una ventanilla si no que simplemente aparece el recuadro en la barra de tarea indicando que esta abierto pero nada aparece al seleccionarlo.

Answer (score 0):

PRoblema resuelto. Elimine todo mi venv para luego ejecutar el reinicio de spyder a traves del script que se encuentra a traves del buscador de archivos de windows bajo el nombre de reset spyder setting.

Comment: Hola MARCELO BRAVO, me alegro que encontraras una solución a tu problema, pero te comento que ha sido reportada como de baja calidad por la comunidad debido a su extensión y contenido. Por favor, edítala para añadir algo más de información: ¿cómo se eliminaría el env? ¿por qué eliminarlo y ejecutar el reinicio soluciona el problema? ¿tienes alguna referencia/fuente que seguiste para solucionar esto? Lee [answer] para más recomendaciones. Saludos.